# How to find the distance between polyData and a point along a direction?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, vtk

I have a point, and a point normal defined to it. Suppose I also have a polydata, which doesn't include or span this point.

I want to find the distance from this point to the polydata along the polydata normal. By distance, I mean how far should I translate the point so that it "touches" the surface defined by polydata.

Is this possible to do with vtk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I am not expert on vtk or any engine package. But your first question is a pure geometric one. Firstly you should compute the plane that polydata lies on it as a point(PlaneDefPoint) in that plane and a plane normal(PlaneDefNormal). 
You may compute it by calculation of cross product of two vectors obtained from three point lies on that plane (in this case three points from your polydata).

```
                   *  Point
PlaneDefNormal    /
               ^ /               
               |/
---------------*-------------------  Plane
         PlaneDefPoint
```

After you obtain plane definitions. Compute vector to the point from the definition point of plane (PlaneDefPoint) and calculate dot product of this vector(inclined one in the figure) with the plane normal(PlaneDefNormal).

Comment: Thank you. I had a similar approach. I calculated point normals and generated lines in these normal directions. I was able to detect the intersection points through the usage of OBB trees and than calculate distances. Anyway, thank you for your advise.

Comment: This method works only for the surface of a "flattened" polydata, not for the surface a generic polydata

Comment: of course..here 2D surface is assumed since neither 3D is not explicitly asked nor details of question leads to 3D.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for intersection with a segment computed on the normal. The method vtkCellLocator::InteresectwithLine will give you the intersection points. The problem with this method is that if the segment is "too short", you will not meet the polydata. If the segment is "too long", you can intersect the polydata twice, and then you have to be careful on the intersection to retrieve. 
For a more complex example, which handle this case (through the use of vtkCellLocator::FindCellsAlongLine ), see the implementation of vtkSelectEnclosedPoints::IsInsideSurface (http://fossies.org/dox/ParaView-v4.1.0-source/vtkSelectEnclosedPoints_8cxx_source.html)